# cfcontent with custom favicon

Tags: html, coldfusion, favicon

I've got a custom favicon that can be set by admins in our web app, so different users can have different favicons. This is from the page header:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://#application.company#/themes/favicon-custom.ico?v=#createUUID()#" />
```

The problem arises when they open a file. I use cfcontent to either download it or display it in the browser depending on the file type.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline;filename=""#variables.fileName#""">
<cfcontent type="#FilegetMimeType(variables.fullFilePath)#" file="#variables.fullFilePath#" DELETEFILE="YES">
```

If it opens up in a new browser tab it uses our app's generic favicon, rather than the customer specific one. I think cfcontent replaces any custom content on the page so it gets overwritten. Is there a way around that or another way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Who is serving `favicon-custom.ico`? It sounds like you are using a rewrite to dynamically serve the icon instead of it being static file, served by your webserver or servlet container? Also, to debug your issue properly, request the favicon with a cacheless HTTP client. Browsers are very stubborn with favicons (cache).

Comment: We are using a rewrite rule to serve the icon from S3, through CloudFront. And it loads correctly on every other page on our site that's not using cfcontent. But cfcontent completely replaces the content on the page with the file it's pointing to. So the link tag is erased.

Comment: That is literally what <cfcontent> is supposed to do. Quoting from the official docs: `"Sends the contents of a file, or of a variable that contains binary data, as the page output."` It is usually used whenever you need to serve content/files dynamically. If you need to display the favicon file on a HTML page, separate page content and the URI of favicon.